# What policies can a government adopt to promote economic equality?

Tags: inequality

As per the Oxfam survey, Top 1% owns more than the bottom 50% of the population. There is also an enormous wage gap emerging, such as that our average CEO makes something like 200x much more than their average worker.

If we put aside the normative question of whether or not it is desirable, what measures can governments adopt to redistribute wealth more evenly?

Comment: Varun, I've edited the question to remove the section of it that sought opinions; and focused on wealth income inequality rather than income inequality - I hope that keeps within your intent for the question

Comment: Varun are you interested in policies in general to combat wealth inequality or only in macroeconomic policies? Macroeconomics as a sub field of economics does not really deal with redistributional questions. For example, a wealth, income tax or estate tax would not be considered macroeconomic policy. There are some macroeconomic policies that could contribute to lowering inequality (for example automatic stabilizers) but are you actually interested only in macroeconomic policies?

Comment: Thank you so much for the edit @EnergyNumbers. It does keep within what I intend to know.

Comment: @1muflon1 that's a really helpful remark and thank you for pointing out the nuance between what I wrote and could've meant. I am interested to know of policies from the standpoint of government like what all policy measures could it take to address this issue.

Comment: @VarunSingh in that case you should edit your question to just policies - otherwise you will get answers only about macroeconomic policies and those are not necessarily best policies to address inequality in the first place

Comment: The main policy would be a progressive tax system, which most countries have in place. The question then becomes how progressive should a tax policy be.